# Correct approach for snapping a route to roads using HERE API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I just want to double check that I am heading in the right direction with what I’m trying to do with the HERE REST API.

I need to provide the API a list of GPS points that will send me back a snap to roads list of points.

From the documentation it looks like this is the correct API:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/route-import.html

But I can't seem to find an example where I can POST the lats/lngs in the response body.

Are there any other approaches I should be considering?